# How to set the selected index of a dropdown in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two dropdowns, the second controlled by the first.  When selecting a value in the first dropdown, it sets a new list of options for the second dropdown.

The problem I have is the selected index of the second dropdown is being remembered, and I don't see a clear way to set the selected index.  If this was just javascript, I'd just set the selected index.  But being react, I'm not sure what I should do.

```
render() {
        let renderWorkItemTypes = (workItemType: TFS_WorkItemTracking_Contracts.WorkItemType) => {
            return <option value={workItemType.name}>{workItemType.name}</option>;
        };

        return <select onChange={this.props.workItemTypeChanged}>{this.props.workItemTypes.map(renderWorkItemTypes) }</select>;
    }
```

Comment: Make the `<select>` a controlled component. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html .

Comment: It is controlled, but the underlying issue was I also needed to reset the state when the properties were updated.

Comment: Well, it's not controlled in your question. Please read [mcve] so that you can provide a better example next time.

Answer (score 4):

I advice you using the props `value` of `<Select>` as described by [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value):

```
<select value="B">
 <option value="A">Apple</option>
 <option value="B">Banana</option>
 <option value="C">Cranberry</option>
</select>
```

When your `onChange` triggers, edit your component state with `setState` and change the `<select>` value: `<select value={this.state.value}>`? Having the select field value depending on your component state allows you to control the default value and therefore to change it when the first select field resets the second select field.

Comment: I was doing that, but I also needed to do the following:
1) Implement componentWillReceiveProps which resets the local state.
2) Implement a local onChange that saves the state before propagating it higher

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was not also resetting the value when new props were coming in.

Final code:

```
class WorkItemTypeDropDown extends React.Component<IWorkItemTypeDropdownProps, any> {
    constructor(props: IWorkItemTypeDropdownProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ""
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: IWorkItemTypeDropdownProps, nextContext: any) {
        this.setState({
            value: ""
        });
    }

    onChange(e: React.FormEvent) {
        let select = e.target as HTMLSelectElement;
        let workItemType = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value");

        this.setState({
            value: workItemType
        });

        this.props.workItemTypeChanged(e);
    }

    render() {
        let renderWorkItemTypes = (workItemType: TFS_WorkItemTracking_Contracts.WorkItemType) => {
            return <option value={workItemType.name}>{workItemType.name}</option>;
        };

        return <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}>{this.props.workItemTypes.map(renderWorkItemTypes) }</select>;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are propagating the value up, then the value should probably be set by the parent, not kept as local state.

Comment: So basically the child will fire the change event, then the parent will update the "global" state and then the props to the child will get that again.  Sure, that makes sense too, and I probably would end up there when I started consuming the property.

Comment: Yep. And the global state knows that whenever X changes it has to reset Y. `WorkItemTypeDropDown` doesn't have to know about this at all, it only shows whatever value it gets passed in.